# Thumbnail missing for Apple generic type wallet pass made with jpasskit

Tags: ios, wallet, passkit

I'm making a generic type pass to the wallet using jpasskit on the server. Pass is created, but the thumbnail is not shown. I've tried resizing both the longest and shortest side by 90pt. The photo I have is at 3x4, so it's within the expected proportion range.

Does anyone have any tips on what I might have missed?

Comment: Have you checked the generated .pkpass bundle to ensure that the thumbnail is included in the bundle and that it is correctly named?

Comment: @PassKit I check the file and thumbnail was there, so I realized that a scorecard type was generated instead of generic. I've fixed the service and now it's working. Thanks.